# нажатия клавиши в консоли

Tags: c#

как при помощи Console.KeyAvailable сделать так, чтобы нажал клавишу и условно переменная count увеличилась на 1. А дальше, чтобы не реагировало. Просто я как ни пытаюсь сделать это, у меня считывается нажатие на протяжении всего времени нажатия. А я пытаюсь сделать так, чтобы если зажал, то сделался один шаг. Вот

```
if (Console.KeyAvailable == false)
{
    key = ConsoleKey.Q;
}
while (Console.KeyAvailable == true)
{
    key = Console.ReadKey(true).Key;
}
```

Comment: Покажите код, который вас не устраивает.

Comment: вот
if (Console.KeyAvailable == false) { key = ConsoleKey.Q; }
while (Console.KeyAvailable == true) { key = Console.ReadKey(true).Key; }